# Compare values in serialized column in Doctrine with Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm building a `FormType` for a Symfony2 project but I need some Query Builder on the field since I need to compare some values with the one stored on DB and show the results. This is what I have:

```
....
->add('servicio', 'entity', array(
    'mapped' => false,
    'class' => 'ComunBundle:TipoServicio',
    'property' => 'nombre',
    'required' => true,
    'label' => false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('ts')
                        ->where('ts.tipo_usuario = (:tipo)')
                        ->setParameter('tipo', 1);
        }
))
....
```

But `tipo_usuario` at DB table is stored as serialized text for example:

```
record1: value1 | a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}
record2: value2 | a:4:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"3";i:3;s:1:"4";}
```

I'll have two different forms (I don't know how to pass the Request to a form) in the first one I'll only show the first record and for the second one the first and second record for example:

First form will show:

```
checkbox: value1
```

Second form will show:

```
checkbox: value1
checkbox: value2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, there is really no clean way to search within a serialized PHP string, especially not with DQL.

If you really need to, and your underlying RDBMS supports it, you could use a native query and use a regex-type query, searching for a certain pattern in the serialized array. But this would be a very crappy solution.

The right way would be to create an additional table/entity in a 1:n (OneToMany) relation.

If you're using a third party bundle and can't modify the schema, you could create some sort of additional lookup table and register an event listener which updates that table each time a record with the serialized array in the other table is persisted.

Then, when making the search query, you make a DQL join on the additional table to filter for the elements you want.